# Characterize the integers $a,b$ satisfying: $ab-1|a^2+b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be two positive integers such that $ab-1|a^2+b^2$.

Show that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab-1}=5$.

Comment: I did this, including the more general $ab-t$ for positive integer $t$ and $ab>t,$ see  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829228/is-it-true-that-fx-y-dfracx2y2xy-t-has-only-finitely-many-distinct-i   Where did you get this problem?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer

Comment: There is a famous and difficult problem of IMO for which if $ab+1|a^2+b^2$ then $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is necessarily a square. (it is clear that it is another problem but  it looks like...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a bunch of pictures which show how the argument goes for this problem. All concepts are shown in detail at [Is it true that $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy-t}$ has only finitely many distinct positive integer values with $x$, $y$ positive integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829228/is-it-true-that-fx-y-dfracx2y2xy-t-has-only-finitely-many-distinct-i)

On the other hand, this one is fairly easy and may help people. The Vieta Jumping argument says that, if there are any integer points $(x,y)$ in the hyperbola $$x^2 - q xy + y^2 = -q,$$ with integers $x,y,q > 0,$ then there are integer points that also satisfy
$$   2x \leq qy  $$
$$ 2y \leq qx.  $$
This viewpoint comes from A. Hurwitz (1907) and clarifies these Vieta Jumping problems nicely.

For now, I am just going to put several diagrams for increasing $q.$ There are no integer points in the central arc for $q=3,4.$ For $q=5$ there are some, namely $(2,1)$ and $(1,2).$ For $q \geq 6$ we see that the central arc has only a very short arc with both $1 \leq x,y \leq 2,$ outside of which there are two fairly long arcs (but still inside the Hurwitz lines) that have either $0 < x < 1$ or $0 < y < 1.$ As a result, there are no integer points satisfying the Hurwitz conditions (which are just the inequalities we get after Vieta Jumping) and therefore no integer points at all.

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]